# SVR: Summation to Matrix Formulation

Tags: summation, matrix-equations

Obtained from *"Engineering Design via Surrogate Modelling: A Practical Guide, Forrester"*, The convex problem is written as

***Maximize,***

$\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j=1}^{n} (\alpha^{+(i)} - \alpha^{-(i)}) (\alpha^{+(j)} - \alpha^{-(j)})\Psi(x^i,x^j) - \epsilon\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\alpha^{+(i)} - \alpha^{-(i)}) + \sum_{i=1}^{n}y^i(\alpha^{+(i)} - \alpha^{-(i)})
$

***Subject to,***

$ \sum_{i=1}^{n}(\alpha^{+(i)} - \alpha^{-(i)}) = 0 $
and $\alpha^{\pm}\in[0,C/n] $

This in turn is changed into a minimize problem by just multiplying by -1, Thus the Matrix formulation is as written.

***Minimize,***
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2}
\begin{bmatrix}
 \alpha^+\\-\alpha^-\\
\end{bmatrix}^T 
\begin{bmatrix}
\Psi & -\Psi\\ -\Psi & \Psi
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
 \alpha^+\\-\alpha^-\\
\end{bmatrix} + 
\begin{bmatrix}
 1^T\epsilon - y\\ 1^T\epsilon + y
\end{bmatrix}^T
\begin{bmatrix}
 \alpha^+\\-\alpha^-\\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

***Subject to,***
\begin{equation}
1^T\begin{bmatrix} \alpha^+\\-\alpha^-\\\end{bmatrix} = 0
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\alpha^+,\alpha^-\in [0, C/n]
\end{equation}

I would like to know the steps for deriving the matrix formulation from the summation.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a step-by-step method for getting this kind of compact (i.e. block-matrix based) formula.  However, here is a method for writing the a quadratic expression in terms of matrices.

Suppose we have a sum of the form 
$$
S = \sum_{i \leq j}^N a_{ij} v^iv^j + \sum_{i=1}^N b_i v^i.
$$
Note that if we take $v = (\alpha^{+(1)}, \dots , \alpha^{+(N)},\alpha^{-(1)}, \dots , \alpha^{-(N)})$, then expanding and rearranging the products in the expression that you are meant to minimize will give you something of the above form.  We can write
$$
S = v^TMv + b^Tv,
$$
where $b = (b_1,\dots,b_N)^T$ and 
$$
M_{ij} = \begin{cases} 
a_{ij} & i=j\\
a_{ij}/2 & i \neq j.
\end{cases}
$$
To understand how your particular objective function was rewritten, I suggest that you apply this idea for the cases of $n=2,n=3$.  After that, I think it should be clear why the given matrix formulas work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I have seen that it works through code. I don't believe i have seen any references that explain the steps for changing the objective function from summation to matrix, which annoys me because i don't know why it works.

Comment: Also, for the equality constraint
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\alpha^{+(i)} - \alpha^{-(i)}) = 0
\end{equation}

In the reference, it is written as.
\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha^+\\ -\alpha^-
\end{bmatrix}

I wonder how they did this and why is it not,
\begin{bmatrix}
(\alpha^+ - \alpha^-)_i\\
.\\
.\\
.\\
(\alpha^+ - \alpha^-)_n
\end{bmatrix}

Comment: @123 Again, the point of this is not to convince you **that** the formula works, but to give you a feeling for **why** the formula works, which is what you seem to be looking for.  There are no "steps for deriving" the matrix formula, but what I gave you is about as close to a general procedure as you can get.

Comment: Right, if you may, would you be able to answer this question? (my second comment)

Comment: @123 One way to think about it is that they rewrote
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\alpha^{+(i)} - \alpha^{-(i)}) = 
\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha^{+(i)} - \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha^{-(i)}.
$$
In terms of the $v$ in my (recently edited) answer, this is just
$$
v_1 + \cdots + v_n - v_{n+1} - \cdots - v_{2n}
$$
which can be written as
$$
(1,\dots,1) (v_1,\dots,v_n,-v_{n+1},\dots,-v_{2n})^T.
$$

Comment: @123 The form you suggest is also correct.  However, it is often convenient to write the vectors in these expressions in such a way that each vector entry contains only one of the variables.

Comment: thank you, now its clear to me