# Summation to Vector form

Tags: summation, vectors

Say i have a summation,

$\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\alpha^{+(i)} - \alpha^{-(i)})$

If i were to change it into vector format it would be,

\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha^+\\ \alpha^-
\end{bmatrix}

In the reference book it is written as,

\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha^+\\ -\alpha^-
\end{bmatrix}

This is obtained from *"Engineering Design via Surrogate Modelling: A Practical Guide, Forrester"* describing the steps for SVR. I am having trouble as to how in Forrester they could change the summation into the vector format as shown above.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "changing a summation into vector format". How exactly is the vector you wrote supposed to be connected to the summation?

Comment: I have written another question related to this, maybe this would make it clear
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3563400/svr-summation-to-matrix-formulation

Comment: Your other question is clear, but what you wrote here still doesn't make sense.  Should there be a $1^T$ in front for this question?